# Distribute elements into bins with conditions

Tags: algorithm

Given a collection of

```
struct Person {
    string name;
    int team;
    bool swimmer;
};

vector<Person> people;
```

is there a "well known" algorithm to distribute them into the least number of fixed-size bins with the following conditions:

1. No two people in the same bin can be from the same team
2. At least one person in each bin must be a swimmer

I'm looking for a solution with the smallest number of bins required to accommodate every Person. The bins do not have to be fully filled.

If half are swimmers and the bin size is four, the easiest solution is to put one swimmer with one non-swimmer. However, the most efficient solution is to put two swimmers and two non-swimmers in a bin (team membership permitting).

The number of different teams can be greater than the size of a bin, so there would be many solutions.

Obviously, if `people.size() / bin_size > number of swimmers`, there would be no solution.

Comment: I wonder if this is a version of a satisfiability problem. Not that that would help you, just thinking out loud.

Comment: Can I assume that bins do not have to be filled?  That is, can 10 people go into 3 bins of size 4 assuming all other conditions are satisfied?

Comment: @Henry The bin size is four, the number of people is not four but several times larger.

Comment: @btilly You are correct, I forgot to mention that bins do not need to be fully filled.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a variant of the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

It's a NP-complete problem but there are plenty of algorithms in literature to solve it, both for online and offline approaches.

In your case you know the data in advance so you may want to the First-fit-decreasing (FFD) algorithm or its modified version, which run in at most `O(nlog(n))`.

You have to modify the standard algorithm to introduce the constraints.

Comment: you've misunderstood the problem, it's not `bin packing` problem...this is a simple ad-hoc problem...you may read the solution, I've written.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to determine `the least number of bins you need`. Actually, you've said it yourself.

Before explaining everything, let's discuss some parameters of this problem:

1. let, the total no. of teams be `T`.
2. let, `n_x` be the number of person in `team x`.
3. let, `s_x` be the number of swimmer in `team x`.

So, the number of bins you need at least should be:

```
number of bins needed = max(n_i), where 1 <= i <= T

cause, as you've said, "No two people in the same bin can be from the same team"

and if `no. of bin` is lesser than that, you've to put two person of same team
in a common bin.
```

Now, let's come to the second condition: `At least one person in each bin must be a swimmer`. To satisfy this condition, we must know the total number of swimmers present in all teams. And the total number of swimmers are:

```
total no. of swimmers = sum(s_i), where 1 <= i <= T
```

And the second condition would fall, if `total no. of swimmers < number of bins needed`. Cause, then, you can never satisfy the second condition.

And, your `bin_size` must be at least:

```
bin_size = ceil( sum(n_i) / number of bins needed ), where 1 <= i <= T
```

If `bin_size` is anyhow lesser than `ceil( sum(n_i) / number of bins needed )`, then again, you'll fail to construct solution. Cause, it'll fail you to satisfy your `first condition`.

I guess, you've got the answer. And the algorithm to determine the `least number of bins` and `put the people in those bins using the two conditions` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The bin size is actually given as an input.  So the least possible number of bins is `max(largest team, number of people / bin size)`.  I'm fairly sure that if there are enough swimmers, a simple greedy approach of will successfully fill in swimmers and then teams.  (Distribute largest team first, swimmers first to bins without swimmers, everyone else to keep bins level with extras going to bins that already have a swimmer.)

Comment: @btilly, you're totally misunderstanding my point of showing the constraint on  `bin_size` here. It does not matter `bin_size` is given as input or not, it must satisfy the constraint to have a solution for given problem. And also, What you've said about `least no. of bins needed` does not guarantee to have a solution. And of course, if all conditions are satisfied as I've described, then there is a solution and of course, a greedy approach would work...its too obvious, anyone can see that...

Comment: If there are 20 teams of 5, and the max bin size is 10, then you'd calculate that 'no. of bins needed' is `max(n_i)` which is 5.  I'm merely pointing out that by the pigeonhole principle, you need at least 10.  The rest of your analysis looks good to me.

Comment: @btilly, you've misunderstood me again, in my answer `no. of bins needed and bin_size` are two different things...and i've applied pigeonhole for `no. of bins needed`..pls take a look again at my answer...